# Update external hosts in Cordova.plist file dynamically

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

Would like to know if there is a way of updating the external hosts in Cordova.plist file at the run time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to do this by now. Could you please provide more information about the use case of such a behaviour.

The only use case I can think of is a ChildBrowser (or any other plugin) and there is some change happening right now. Shazron mentioned in his lastest [blogpost](http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/inappbrowser-based-on-childbrowser-in-cordova-2-3-0/) that the external hosts whitelist in the Cordova.plist will only affect the main WebView, but not the ChildBrowser with 2.3.0. Generally there will be [white-list exception enhancements for plugins](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1889).

Of course you can always use the `*` wildcard to allow any kind of external host.